# Git is silently failing after push/pull

Tags: git, version-control, ssh, repository

I'm a one-person IT department managing our company's website and recently recommended they have me set up version control. I've read all the tutorials and have heard everyone else's version of the *best* workflow, however, I'm starting with a humble setup until I can get this simple workflow operational.

**Problem:** After setting this up, The push and pull works fine (i.e. it presents no errors), but I don't actually see the changes show up either on my local machine or on the server.

1. I started by doing a git init to the /var/www/ folder.
2. Then, I cloned the remote repository via SSH to my local machine.

   *At this point, the files from my server show up in my local repository, no problem.*
3. On my local machine, I added a branch to the repo called "development"
4. Added a new line of text to an HTML doc on my local machine.
5. Staged and committed the HTML doc on the development branch.
6. Pushed to the server.

   *At this point, the changes do not show up.*
7. On the master branch on the server, I added a line to the html file, a random jumble of text.
8. Staged and committed the change.
9. On my local machine, I pulled from the master branch on the remote repository.

Again, no errors. But the changes do not show up. The file on the server and on my local machine reflect the original contents and the respective changes I made on each one.

Comment: Did you `git init` or `git init --bare` on the remote machine?

Comment: It let you push to a non-bare repository?

Comment: Plain init. The --bare didn't seem right for what I was doing.

Comment: WOW. After playing with this some more, git actually typed into my document and ruined it: http://50.56.241.135/tee-links/file1.html

Comment: I thought this was a tool professionals use, are we really at risk of having git destroy our work like this?

Comment: it's not destroying your work, it's telling you there are conflicts to resolve, see http://www.gitguys.com/topics/merging-with-a-conflict-conflicts-and-resolutions/ for more

Comment: Ohhh, so these markings are meant to help me resolve it myself? Okay, I thought it was just going berserk. Now I'm no longer panicking about having to switch to a different service. Thanks, Luke.

Comment: There's a bit of a learning curve learning git but once you do, it's worth it :) Yes, conflict markers are left in the problematic files where git could not auto-merge (i.e. conflicts on same line coming from multiple branches). You can read up via google or that link I gave you on how to resolve such as through a gui like kdiff3 that will be more readable for you. I personally use BeyondCompare. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you push into a remote repository, it only updates the repo's data -- the files don't get checked out/updated. You can solve this by adding a post-receive hook that runs `git checkout -f`.

Comment: Thanks @mipadi I just looked at the gitbook documentation on this. So would I add a .sh file into the /hooks folder with "git checkout -f" as the script?

Comment: @ajkochanowicz [Here's a how-to on this approach](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto).  Hasn't been updated in a while and I haven't tried it, but give it a try.